# Pass Dictionary in QueryParameters using Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to pass a dictionary through my controller using .Net Web Api.

Unfortunately it isn't working as described at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#dictionaries-1).

My code looks the following:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{key}")]
public ResponseType SearchObjects([FromUri] string key, 
    [FromUri]Dictionary<string, string> options) {}
```

The parameter 'index' works, but the parameter 'options' is always empty (length=0)...

Requests I've tried so far:

> http://localhost/key?index=1&filter[foo]=bar
>
> http://localhost/key?index=1&filter['foo']=bar
>
> http://localhost/key?index=1&filter.foo=bar

Anyone sees what I'm missing? 
Are there any steps to debug/simulate the serialisation?

Comment: why do you want to pass dictionary as URI parameter? it is better to send dictionary as body

Comment: The method is "GET".

Comment: That didn't really answer the question.

Comment: It is an option but I'm forced to do this like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSON! Just add the [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) Package

Some thing like:

```
    [HttpGet("{json}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync([FromRoute] string json)
    {
        var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, string>>(json);
        return await Task.FromResult(Ok());
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Exemple of JSON:

```
{ "Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2", "Key3": "Value3" }
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. I need to pass the filter parameters through queryparameters. How does encoding has an impact in this? What if the client isn't c# (i.e. postman)? there it would be extreamly painful to encode

Comment: I fix it to another resolutions! Check it out Oswald

Answer (score 0):

My solution now is a bit hacky but it seems that there isn't any better way at the moment...

There is a Method parameter just as before. To pass around the problem, that the Web Api not fills the dictionary automatically, I've implemented my own method... (If the Web Api does it in a later release, it will be simle to remove the method and everything should work then...

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("{key}")]
public ResponseType SearchObjects([FromUri] string key, [FromUri] Dictionary<string, string> options)
{
    AddMatchingQueryParamsToDictionary(Request, nameof(options), options);
    //options are now ready to use
}


/// <summary>
/// Fills the dictionary with additional values found in query parameters
/// In the query parameters given by the request, dictionary items will be in the format "dictName.dictKey".
/// </summary>
private static void AddMatchingQueryParamsToDictionary(HttpRequestMessage request, string dictionaryModelName, IDictionary<string, string> dictionaryToFill)
{
    var queryParams = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
    queryParams
        .Where(pair => pair.Key.StartsWith(dictionaryModelName))
        .Select(pair =>
        {
            var key = pair.Key;
            var index = key.IndexOf(dictionaryModelName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            var newKey = index < 0 ? key : key.Remove(index, dictionaryModelName.Length + 1 /*the dot*/);
            return (key: newKey, value: pair.Value);
        }).ToList()
        .ForEach(pair => dictionaryToFill[pair.key] = pair.value);
}
```

What do you think about this solution?